# Windows Phone - Is it possible to change the theme color on the phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My question is simple.

Is it possible to change the theme color of the phone running my app? To be clear, I do not mean the theme of the *app*, but the theme of the actual phone. As you can manually change in Settings -> Theme -> Color.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to change the phone's actual theme with the current SDK (on WP7 or WP8).

Comment: While I can see an edge case for an app to have a button or whatever to change the phone theme, having the ability in the SDK would make it easy for an app to do it without user interaction or permission. While Microsoft could try to deny app submissions that do this, more likely it'll never be added to the SDK.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe or Microsoft could just implement a permission flow the way they have for the PhoneCallTask and ask the user if he/she really wishes to switch from one theme to another!